# Getting rid of autofollowed games on Xbox app feed

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network, xbox-app

I clicked follow on none of the games on the Xbox app. Certainly not on Minecraft. Yet I keep getting spammed with "Minecraft streamed for 1h 54min".

I launched Minecraft on Nintendo Switch once or twice, and logged in with my Microsoft account, a few months ago. I'm now continuously spammed on Xbox with useless posts about the game I actually don't care about.

Because at some point I might want to follow some game, how do I get rid of Minecraft posts, without turning off all "Games you follow" posts in the filter icon on the top right of the Activity Feed screen?

This problem applies to all platforms (Windows 10, Android, ...).

[image: activity feed]

Comment: May I suggest following them and than unfollow them again? It could be some database sync issue and that might fix it.

Comment: Tried previously. No effect. The game was not followed before, and it still appears after follow-unfollow cycle. (Sidenote: It would be surprising to me if I ever manually clicked Follow, as Minecraft is one of those games that I have a strong NON-interest in.)